# Generate android theme at runtime

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Our design asks for some activities whose accent color is set at runtime. That accent color is used for different part of the UI (button text, background color, ...).

Ideally I'd like to set generate a theme at runtime, to use for the activity. The theme would be based on a static one defined in the app resources, but with one style attribute set dynamically (accentColor).

I haven't found a way to do that. Did I miss something?

Comment: You can't create a theme programmatically. But buttons and everything often use 9patch images. You could use one white image and use SetColorFilter to change it to what you want, but you would need to change manually every view and it would still be hard to change actionbar accent color and stuff like that.
So I guess you should generate 10 different themes and just change it at the start of an activity.

Comment: 10 different themes would work if I knew the values of accentColor at build time, but they come from our backend

Comment: Then either increase the amount of theme you'll be packing inside the app or reduce the color theme choice in your backend. I'm affraid nothing magical can be done here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you mean but you can change the color, or other attributes programmatically of any view in Android such as **view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)**, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Sure I can do that but I would have to set the color on each element that uses that color, in each of the activities that get their accent color at runtime. That's what I do now, but it would be a lot nicer if all these views could just refer to a style attribute that I can set at runtime.